# load table from bigquery to spark cluster with pyspark script

Tags: python, apache-spark, google-bigquery, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

I have a data table loaded in bigquery, and I want to import it in my spark cluster via a pyspark .py file.

I saw in [Dataproc + BigQuery examples - any available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32960707/dataproc-bigquery-examples-any-available) that there was a way to load a bigquery table in the spark cluster with scala, but is there a way to do it in a pyspark script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This comes from @MattJ in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31401239/bigquery-connector-for-pyspark-via-hadoop-input-format-example). Here's an example to connect to BigQuery in Spark and perform a word count.

```
import json
import pyspark
sc = pyspark.SparkContext()

hadoopConf=sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
hadoopConf.get("fs.gs.system.bucket")

conf = {"mapred.bq.project.id": "<project_id>", "mapred.bq.gcs.bucket": "<bucket>",
    "mapred.bq.input.project.id": "publicdata", 
    "mapred.bq.input.dataset.id":"samples", 
    "mapred.bq.input.table.id": "shakespeare"  }

tableData = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(
    "com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.JsonTextBigQueryInputFormat",
    "org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable", "com.google.gson.JsonObject", 
    conf=conf).map(lambda k: json.loads(k[1])).map(lambda x: (x["word"],
    int(x["word_count"]))).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y)

print tableData.take(10)
```

You will need to change `<project_id>` and `<bucket>` to match the settings for your project.